# Writing the Contents of Multiple Tables to Output

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working with SQL in an Oracle database. I have several tables that I need to extract the data from for analysis in another program. I am trying to efficiently implement this process.

The final product will be a .csv type file, example:

```
TableName1, Data1, Data2, Data3
TableName1, Data1, Data2, Data3
TableName2, Data1, Data2, Data3, Data4
TableName2, Data1, Data2, Data3, Data4
TableName3, Data1, Data2
```

etc.

Using these queries, I get the data I need and the number of fields so I can use it in a possible for loop:

```
    SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE_NAME
    SELECT count(column_name) FROM all_tab_cols WHERE table_name = 'MY_TABLE_NAME'
```

Where I am lost though is how to translate this into a block though. I will have to run this code again in the future, so I would like the ability to write an array at the beginning with the names of each table I want and be able to add or remove tables later if I need to. Each table also has a different number of fields and data types for each field. All the approaches I have tried so far require me to explicitly state each of these in a DEFINE block, which is not feasible. What is the best way to dynamically loop through these data sets?

Can someone point me in the right direction on where to go next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to write a loop (or anything to do with procedures and PL/SQL) for this. What you do need are two things: a table with the names of the tables you want included (as you said, this may change over time - the best place for the set of tables is a... table), and a query.

In the solution below I created a mock table called `table_names` with a column `tn` in the first factored subquery (in the `with` clause). In real life, delete that CTE, and use your actual table and column names. The columns in the `LISTAGG` are aggregated in the order in which they would appear in a `SELECT *` (which is identified by `COLUMN_ID` in `USER_TAB_COLUMNS`).

I illustrate this with tables from the `SCOTT` schema. Notice what happens when my table of table_names includes a table that does not exist in the schema: the resulting string shows the table name, a comma and a space, and nothing else. This is the result of `OUTER JOIN`. If you don't want such non-existing tables to be included, you can change that to `INNER JOIN`. (You may also write a different query to check first that all the table names actually do exist in the schema they are supposed to be in.)

I also didn't write this to work across different owners/schemas. If that's what you need, it could be adapted easily. In particular, you would use `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` instead of `USER_TAB_COLUMNS`.

**Query**:

```
with table_names ( tn ) as (
       select 'PINOCCHIO'  from dual union all
       select 'EMAIL_ADDRESSES' from dual union all
       select 'BONUS'           from dual union all
       select 'ORDER_ITEM'      from dual
     )
select t.tn, t.tn || ', ' || listagg(c.column_name, ', ') 
                                     within group (order by c.column_id) as str
from table_names t left outer join user_tab_columns c
                 on t.tn = c.table_name
group by tn
;
```

**Output**:

(remember, I am connected as user `SCOTT` - a standard schema that is present by default in any installation of Oracle DB... the password is "tiger" unless you changed it)

```
TN              STR
--------------- ----------------------------------------------------------
BONUS           BONUS, ENAME, JOB, SAL, COMM
EMAIL_ADDRESSES EMAIL_ADDRESSES, INTERNET_ADDRESS_ID, EMAIL_ADDRESS
ORDER_ITEM      ORDER_ITEM, ORDER_ID, ITEM_ID, QTY
PINOCCHIO       PINOCCHIO,

4 rows selected.
```

Comment: That works like a champ for taking that column of field names and concatenating them out. A follow up question though, I can only seem to sort it alphabetically. How do I maintain the structure there? For example, if my fields are layed out 'B', 'C', 'A', how do I keep them being rearranged with LISTAGG to 'A, B, C'?

Comment: They are not ordered alphabetically (see COMM as the last one in the BONUS table?) I explained it in my answer: the ordering is by COLUMN_ID, from the USER_TAB_COLUMNS table. It is the same order in which they would appear if you executed a SELECT * FROM <table_name> statement.

Comment: Ah ha! I missed that line, my apologies. Thank you very much, that worked like a champ.